# How to order the XML element using the child node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to sort the XML elements in ascending order based on the values of the inner attributes "Top".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Root>
      <Designer>
        <Sequence>
          <Left>603.875</Left>
          <Top>312.665</Top>
          <total>NaN</total>
          <Width>58.5</Width>
          <Height>45.5</Height>
          <ID>635b1aed-6ee3-4cf5-9324-b0246f3a0c1d</ID>
          <zIndex>0</zIndex>
          <IsGroup>false</IsGroup>
          <ParentID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ParentID>    
          <ItemLabel>123</ItemLabel>
        </Sequence>
        <Sequence>
          <Left>568.875</Left>
          <Top>29.664999999999992</Top>
          <total>NaN</total>
          <Width>58.5</Width>
          <Height>45.5</Height>
          <ID>9dd9a96d-4356-49c6-85a3-6b898983e688</ID>
          <zIndex>1</zIndex>
          <IsGroup>false</IsGroup>
          <ParentID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ParentID>
          <ItemLabel>321</ItemLabel>
        </Sequence>
      </Designer>
<Parameters>
<Value> 
<Name> Label 1 </Name>
<ID> 1 </ID>
</Value>
<Value> 
<Name> Label 2 </Name>
<ID> 2 </ID>
</Value>
</Parameters>

</Root>
```

And here is my code which I have tried.

```
   try
   {
         XElement root = XElement.Load(MainWindow.Container.globalfilename +".xml");
         var orderedtabs = root.Elements("Designer").Elements("Sequence")
                                      .OrderBy(xtab => (float)xtab.Element("Top"))
                                      .ToArray();

         foreach (XElement tab in orderedtabs)
         {
                    root.Add(tab);
         }
         root.Save("xmlfile" + ".xml");
         MessageBox.Show("Sorted");
   }
```

While I try to create a new XML file,  tag gets deleted. but i can able to write in order from . 
However,   and elements of it gets deleted.

Kindly provide me answers or corrections where I am going wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would do a `GroupBy(x => x.Element("Top").Value).OrderBy()`....

Comment: And what is the exact problem with your code? What happens when you run it?

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer While writing, the <Designer> tag gets deleted and also the other tags like <Parameters> <Value> gets deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Root, Designer and Parameters tags get deleted because you select only the Sequences tags which you then add to the top of you root. I suggest to remove all Sequences tags below Designer and reinsert the ordered Sequences under Designer again:

```
        XElement root = XElement.Load("input.xml");
        // Extract Sequences ordered by 'Top'
        var orderedtabs = root.Elements("Designer").Elements("Sequence")
                              .OrderBy(xtab => (float)xtab.Element("Top"))
                              .ToArray();
        // Remove Sequences from xml
        root.Descendants("Designer").Elements("Sequence").Remove();
        // Reinsert Sequences in new order under the Designer element
        XElement designer = root.Descendants("Designer").FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (XElement tab in orderedtabs)
        {
            designer.Add(tab);
        }
        root.Save("xmlfile" + ".xml");
```